# Parcelable protocol requires that the class implements Parcelable

Tags: java, android, parcelable, badparcelableexception

Some times, I got this error, i don't know what is wrong in my code Please
help!

Any suggestion code it will help.

Here it is my error report:

```
com.example E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires that the class implements Parcelable
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                               Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires that the class implements Parcelable
                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2407)
                                                                                  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
                                                                                  at android.view.AbsSavedState.<init>(AbsSavedState.java:57)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$BaseSavedState.<init>(View.java:22902)
                                                                                  at com.example.DrawableViewSaveState.<init>(DrawableViewSaveState.java:17)
                                                                                  at com.example.DrawableViewSaveState$1.createFromParcel(DrawableViewSaveState.java:43)
                                                                                  at com.example.DrawableViewSaveState$1.createFromParcel(DrawableViewSaveState.java:41)
```

And Here it is my DrawableViewSaveState class:

And this error happend when i want go back to my acivity that use the DrawableViewSaveState class.
I'm always getting the crash in super(in);

```
public class DrawableViewSaveState extends View.BaseSavedState {

    private ArrayList<SerializablePath> paths;

    public DrawableViewSaveState(Parcel in) {
        super(in);  // I'm always getting the crash in this line of code.
        this.paths = (ArrayList<SerializablePath>) in.readSerializable();
        for (SerializablePath p : paths) {
            p.loadPathPointsAsQuadTo();
        }
    }

    public DrawableViewSaveState(Parcelable parcelable) {
        super(parcelable);
    }

    @Override public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeSerializable(this.paths);
    }

    public ArrayList<SerializablePath> getPaths() {
        return paths;
    }

    public void setPaths(ArrayList<SerializablePath> paths) {
        this.paths = paths;
    }

    public static final Creator<DrawableViewSaveState> CREATOR =
            new Creator<DrawableViewSaveState>() {
                public DrawableViewSaveState createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                    return new DrawableViewSaveState(source);
                }

                public DrawableViewSaveState[] newArray(int size) {
                    return new DrawableViewSaveState[size];
                }
            };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of parent class attempts to read Parcelable from Parcel. Unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately — at least you avoided silent data corruption!), Parcel does not contain expected Parcelable.

The reason is because you are violating expectation of the parent class. As can be seen from [source code of AbsSavedState](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/AbsSavedState.java#56), the constructor, that accepts a `Parcel`, expects to see a Parcelable, received by your `DrawableViewSaveState(Parcelable parcelable)` constructor, — e.g. the state of parent `View` class):

```
protected AbsSavedState(Parcel source) {
    // FIXME need class loader
    Parcelable superState = source.readParcelable(null);

    mSuperState = superState != null ? superState : EMPTY_STATE;
}
```

That Parcelable is [written to Parcel](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/AbsSavedState.java#70) by `writeToParcel()` of your superclass, but you are not calling it!

Solution: add call to `super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);` to the beginning of your `writeToParcel` method.

Future lesson: if you inherit from Parcelable classes, consider calling writeToParcel of superclass from your writeToParcel method.

Comment: Thank you very very much user1643723, it worked for me.